# Programming a sensitivity analysis in R: Vary 1 parameter (column), hold others constant. Better way?

Tags: r, dataframe, combinations

I want to test the sensitivity of a calculation to the value of 4 parameters. To do this, I want to vary one parameter at a time -- i.e., change Variable 1, hold variables 2-4 at a "default" value (e.g., 1).  I thought an easy way to organize these values would be in a data.frame(), where each column corresponds to a different variable, and each row to a set of parameters for which the calculation should be made.  I would then loop through each row of the data frame, evaluating a function given the parameter values in that row.

This seems like it should be a simple thing to do, but I can't find a quick way to do it.

The problem might be my overall approach to programming the sensitivity analysis, but I can't think of a good, simple way to program the aforementioned data.frame.

My code for generating the data.frame:

```
Adj_vals <- c(seq(0, 1, by=0.1), seq(1.1, 2, by=0.1)) #a series of values for 3 of the parameters to use
A_Adj_vals <- 10^(seq(1,14,0.5)) #a series of values for another one of the parameters to use
n1 <- length(Adj_vals)
n2 <- length(A_Adj_vals)

data.frame(
    "Dg_Adj"=c(Adj_vals, rep(1, n1*2+n2)),  #this parameter's default is 1
    "Df_Adj"=c(rep(1, n1), Adj_vals, rep(1, n1+n2)), #this parameter's default is 1
    "sd_Adj"=c(rep(1, n1*2), 0.01, Adj_vals[-1], rep(1, n2)), #This parameter has  default of 1, but unlike the others using Adj_vals, it can only take on values >0
    "A"=c(rep(1E7, n1*3), A_Adj_vals) #this parameter's default is 10 million
)
```

This code produces the desired data.frame.  Is there a simpler way to achieve the same result? I would accept an answer where `sd_Adj` takes on `0` instead of `0.01`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's pretty debatable if this is better, but another way to do it would be to follow this pattern:

```
defaults<-data.frame(a=1,b=1,c=1,d=10000000)
merge(defaults[c("b","c","d")],data.frame(a=c(seq(0, 1, by=0.1), seq(1.1, 2, by=0.1))))
```

This should be pretty easy to cook up into a function that automatically removes the correct column from defaults based on the column name in the data frame you are merging with etc